# Populate fields from Contact onto Opportunity when a "New Opportunity" button on contact is Clicked

Tags: opportunity, contact, java, button, opportunitycontactrole

I created a button on Contact which is supposed to create a new opportunity, populate fields and create an Opportunity Contact Role on Opportunity when a Sales Rep clicks on New Opportunity Button.

I used URL hacking method to achieve this and I did succeed. To achieve this, I used a formula checkbox that checks if the Opportunity is created from contact using the CONTACT CASESAFEID on the Opportunity that populates when the button is created.

The problem I'm facing here is, I could see the button working perfectly when I(Admin) click the button, but when I log in as Sales Rep and click the button, I don't see that happening. I'm surprised why?

Checked all permission sets nothing blocks them. Couldn't figure out why this doesn't work for non admin profile. It will be very helpful if someone helps me with this
.
Thanks!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code for your URL hack button. Consider using a Quick Action instead - URL hacks are not supported in Lightning.

Comment: Have you checked Field Level Security on the fields being used in the formula?